# Too much blank space under each card, using reactjs-social-embed

Tags: reactjs, facebook-graph-api, bootstrap-4

I am making a webpage using react where I want to display every post in a facebook page. I am using this package to display each post and Facebook graph API to get each postID then I map it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactjs-social-embed

My problem is that there is just too much blank space under each facebook post([See img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHodx.png)). Id like each post to be positioned right on top of eachother.

If I try to change the height to auto or 100% the Like btn, comment, and share btn disappears.

```
        return (
        <>
            {fbData.map((post) => (
                <div style={{paddingTop: 40}}
                     className="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 container justify-content-center">
                    <Row>
                            <Facebook type="post"
                                      width="800px"
                                      height="680px"
                                      url={`https://www.facebook.com/102417811874407/posts/${post.id.split("_")[1]}`} />
                    </Row>
                </div>
            )
            )}
        </>
    );
};
export default Nyheter;
```

The facebook API does not return img size either :/
[This is how it looks if I try to change each post to 200px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQeoF.png)

Comment: have you tried to remove the `justify-content-center` from the `div`

Comment: These plugins load in iframes, which won’t automatically adapt to the height of their content. The JS SDK Facebook provides usually automatically adjusts them, but for that it needs to be embedded in the parent document. (Can’t tell whether that is actually the case here with this implementation, or whether it uses the iframe embed code directly.)